# Mirrored taskbar icons

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

My brother tried to install some junk on his laptop (Windows 7) and ever since then the icons in the taskbar got mirrored. I tried rebuilding IconCache.db but it didn't work the problem out. He says he only tried to install alternative orbs for start button but I can't be sure.

Any ideas?

[image: taskbar]

Comment: Is it *only* the taskbar buttons?

Comment: `It's just the taskbar icons that are mirrored, not even the clock and date. That's some weird stuff.` Is the notification area (“tray”) with the clock on the right or left side of the screen?

Comment: @Synetech Left, that's an RTL system

Comment: Have you tried system restore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed normal for RTL systems to have the start-orb on the right and tray on the left (figures 1 and 2), but notice that the icons in the taskbar face the same way as the ones on a LTR system (figure 3). In your screenshot, the Explorer icon is indeed facing backwards (though the start-orb is facing the right way).

What has likely happened is that the taskbar-modifying program that he installed did not support “[i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I18n)” correctly, if at all, and the modifications it made broke something.

Without knowing specifically which program it is, there’s not much anyone can do, and even then, the damage may be specific to that system.

Your/his best chance, in order of difficulty/complication is as follows:

- Use the *undo/reset* function of the program to hopefully revert its changes
- Fully uninstsall the program (re-installing it first if necessary)
- Try running the [System-File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) in case the program modified system files
- Perform a [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to the point before the program was used if possible
- Try the [Recovery Options](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-vista)
- Fall back to a [repair-install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)
- As a last resort, do a full re-install and learn a lesson the hard way about trying random software and not backing up

**Figure 1**: Arabic Windows 7

[image: Arabic Windows 7]

**Figure 2**: Hebrew Windows 7

[image: Hebrew Windows 7]

**Figure 3**: English Windows 7

[image: English Windows 7]

Comment: But notice how `S` on Skype icon is mirrored and `P` as well. That means icons pictures are mirrored as well. IMO if it would be 'Hebrew issue' than icons would not be mirrored.

Comment: Exactly, look at the colors of the windows icon, they are mirrored, also the Office icons are. My problem is not that the orb is in the right side but the flipped icons.

Comment: @Nikolay, Eran; yes, I know. Re-read my post; I already said that the *taskbar button icons are backwards*. The Skype icon is irrelevant/extraneous. Look carefully at the screenshots; the Explorer icon on the (RLT) Arabic and Hebrew buttons face the right way, but it’s backwards in Eran’s screenshot. It’s not “a Hebrew issue”; whatever program Eran’s bother used did not support RTL, so whatever changes it made, messed up the taskbar on an RTL system. Maybe the dev *thought* they were handling RTL by mirroring the buttons, or maybe they did it as a prank. We don’t even know what program it was.

Comment: @Synetech, you right. If it would happen to me I would try system restore...

Answer (score 1):

I think your graphic card setting is manipulated.

1. try right-click on desktop and choose screen resolution. then  then check the Orientation 
   property to Landscape that may solve your problem .
2. check your graphic card 'Rotate' property to 'Normal'
3. at last check windows project by pressing windows key+P and select 'PC Screen Only'

Comment: That’s the first thing that came to my mind as well when I saw the screenshot, but then the text and everything else would be backwards too and they would have asked that instead of just focusing on the taskbar. Plus, if it was the video-card driver/software orientation, then the screen would be upside-down, not backwards.

Comment: Exactly. @Synetech is right. It's just the taskbar icons that are mirrored, not even the clock and date. That's some weird stuff.